# How to add a space after special characters in bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, echo

I have a text file with something like,

```
!aa
@bb
#cc
$dd
%ee
```

expected output is,

```
! aa
@ bb
# cc
$ dd
% ee
```

What I have tried, `echo "${foo//@/@ }"`.

This does work fine with one string but it does not work for all the lines in the file. I have tried with this while loop to read all the lines of the file and do the same using echo but it does not work.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    foo=$line
    sep="!@#$%"
    echo "${foo//$sep/$sep }"
done < $1
```

I have tried with awk split but it does not give the expected output. Is there any workaround for this? by using awk or sed.

Comment: How do you define "special characters"? Is it exactly the set of chars in your question (`!@#$%`) or all punctuation chars or all non-alphabetic chars or something else? Or do you really just want a blank added between the first 2 chars on each line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following assumes you want to add a space after every character in the `!@#$%` set (even if it is the last character in a line). Test file:

```sh
$ cat file.txt
a!a
@bb
c#c
$dd
ee%
foo
%b%r
$ sep='!@#$%'
```

With `sed`:

```sh
$ sed 's/['"$sep"']/& /g' file.txt
a! a
@ bb
c# c
$ dd
ee% 
foo
% b% r
```

With `awk`:

```sh
$ awk '{gsub(/['"$sep"']/,"& "); print}' file.txt
a! a
@ bb
c# c
$ dd
ee% 
foo
% b% r
```

With plain `bash` (not recommended, it is too slow):

```sh
$ while IFS= read -r line; do
    str=""
    for (( i=0; i<${#line}; i++ )); do
      char="${line:i:1}"      
      str="$str$char"
      [[ "$char" =~ [$sep] ]] && str="$str "
    done
    printf '%s\n' "$str"
  done < file.txt
a! a
@ bb
c# c
$ dd
ee% 
foo
% b% r
```

Or (not sure which is the worst):

```sh
$ while IFS= read -r line; do
    for (( i=0; i<${#sep}; i++ )); do
      char="${sep:i:1}"
      line="${line//$char/$char }"
    done
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
  done < file.txt
a! a
@ bb
c# c
$ dd
ee% 
foo
% b% r
```

Answer (score 1):

Characters you call *special* in your example seems to be subset of characters known as `[[:punct:]]` to GNU `sed`, thus I propose following solution:

```
sed 's/\([[:punct:]]\)/\1 /g' file.txt
```

which with `file.txt` content being

```
!aa
@bb
#cc
$dd
%ee
```

output

```
! aa
@ bb
# cc
$ dd
% ee
```

Explanation: I use capturing group `\(`...`\)` which has any character belonging to `[:punct:]` then I replace what was captured with content of that capture followed by space. I use `g` to apply it to all occurences in each line, though this has not visible impact for data above. You might elect to drop `g` if you are sure there will be at most one character to replace in every line.

If you want to know more about `[:punct:]` or other similar character sets read about [Character Classes on Regular-Expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html)

Answer (score 0):

If the file always contain a symbol at the start of line like that then use this

```
sed -Ei 's/^(.)/\1 /g' yourfile.txt
```

The `-E` option is to tell `sed` to use regex. `-i` modifies the file inline, you can remove it if you want to output to console or another file. The `^(.)` regex captures the first character on the line and add a space to it (`\1` )

Comment: `sed` always uses regex, `-E` indicates to use extended regex on some platforms

Comment: The `/g` option is useless here; the regex can obviously only match once per line.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `special characters` are non-numeric and non-alphabetic characters, and special characters can appear `anywhere` in the line, use the following regular expression to replace them.

```
sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/& /g' urfile
```